# Removing attributes to individual nodes in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Here's my XML source

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tns:Grand_Parent_XML xmlns:tns="http://www.domain.com/">
  <GrandParent>
    <Parent>
        <Child xmlns:tns="http://www.domain.com/">
            <Age>3</Age>
            <Gender>Male</Gender>
            <Name>Todd</Name>
        </Child>
        <Other>1234</Other>
    </Parent>
  </GrandParent>
</tns:Grand_Parent_XML>
```

And here's the body of the XSLT I'm using...

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
             <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
             </xsl:copy>
       </xsl:template>
       <xsl:template match="Grand_Parent_XML">
             <xsl:element name="tns:{name()}" namespace="http://www.domain.com/">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="namespace::*"/>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
             </xsl:element>
       </xsl:template>

       <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:if test="normalize-space(string(.)) != ''">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
        </xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Parent">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <Child>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Child/*"/>
        </Child>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Child"/>
```

I want to remove the xmlns:tns="" on the Child and keep it in the Grand_Parent_XML. I've tried other suggestions here like creating the following code in the bottom of the XSLT but it doesn't work. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
<xsl:template match="Child">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: `xmlns:tns=""` is invalid. Prefixed namespace bindings may not be empty.

Comment: Your input XML is not well-formed. If you do not change the namespace definition no stylesheet will accept it as input. Or set the XML version to `1.1`.

Comment: Sorry, I omitted the original content. I'll update it now.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue. Which processor are you using? -- Unrelated to your question, but you have too many templates and some of the elements have ambiguous rule match.

Comment: And of course, that's not really your *input*, is it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25518795/aggregate-multiple-nodes-to-a-single-node-in-xslt

Comment: yes @michael.hor257k ;)

Comment: Well then your stylesheet makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

A simple identity transform removes the redundant namespace declaration, nothing more. Tested with Saxon 6.5 an 9.5.

Before your edit, your XML input had a namespace declaration like

```
xmlns:tns=""
```

Note that *undeclaring* a namespace is illegal in XML 1.0, but possible in XML 1.1. The XML parser would not have raised an error if you had changed the preamble of your file to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Input**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tns:Grand_Parent_XML xmlns:tns="http://www.domain.com/">
  <GrandParent>
    <Parent>
        <Child xmlns:tns="http://www.domain.com/">
            <Age>3</Age>
            <Gender>Male</Gender>
            <Name>Todd</Name>
        </Child>
        <Other>1234</Other>
    </Parent>
  </GrandParent>
</tns:Grand_Parent_XML>
```

**XML Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<tns:Grand_Parent_XML xmlns:tns="http://www.domain.com/">
   <GrandParent>
      <Parent>
         <Child>
            <Age>3</Age>
            <Gender>Male</Gender>
            <Name>Todd</Name>
         </Child>
         <Other>1234</Other>
      </Parent>
   </GrandParent>
</tns:Grand_Parent_XML>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I have used Saxon 6.5.5